# How to convert a PowerShell class method to a ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert a PowerShell class method to a scriptblock.

Without using classes, I can do this:

```
function foo() { 'bar' }
${function:foo} # this will display: 'bar'
```

However, the equivalent doesn't work when using classes. For example, the following doesn't work:

```
class FooBar {
  foo() { 'bar' }
}

$foobar = new-object FooBar

${function:$foobar.foo} # doesn't work
```

I am not surprised the above doesn't work, as class methods are actually implemented as scriptblocks, not functions, but I can't seem to access the underlying code that implements the method. These attempts also don't work:

```
${scriptblock:$foobar.foo}
${scriptblock:FooBar.foo}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is [void], turn to [string] then convert call to scriptblock:

```
class FooBar {
  [string]foo() { return 'bar' }
}

$foobar = new-object FooBar

$scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create('$foobar.foo()') 

$(.$scriptBlock)
```

Comment: I've provided a very simple example, but in practice, the scriptblock needs to be an exact copy of the source code used in the class method, and the approach needs to work independently of the return type of the method. So in your modified example, the scriptblock should be: "return 'bar'" not just 'bar'.

Comment: A delegate using the function: provider is only a pointer to the function, but does not show the source code.Your first example 'bar' ist the output, in this special case the same as the source code itself. What you want is some sort of a decompiler, which returns the sourcecode of a function/method to get used in a scriptblock.